# Script for auto-starting programs after restart

Tags: linux, linux-mint, scripting

Is there any script or program to make all open programs auto start after the system restart? Like the one on the mac that gives you the option to reopen all programs after restart or shutdown

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? E.g. Gnome, KDE, Xfce, …

Comment: Cinnamon Desktop environment

Comment: @WassimSeifeddine KDE has the "save session" option. It starts the last saved session on reboot(if you set it up that way in settings). I use it on Fedora 21 on different machines. That way I have set different programs to auto-start after boot.

Comment: Do u have any idea on how to setup this on cinnamon ?